# How do I place ps -o pid --ppid parent to a variable

Tags: linux, bash

I rather new to Linux bash, I would like to capture the following information into a variable.
Here is how I did it in my script, but I received errors?

```
child=$(ps -o pid --ppid "$reponse")
echo "This is your child process : $child"
```

Errors received:

```
Error: List of process IDs must follow --ppid
```

Note: when I run the command `ps -o pid --pid nnnnn` (where `nnnnn` is the Parent Id) on the command line, I receive this output to the screen:

```
PID
mmmmm
```

(where `mmmmm` is the child ID). What I want is the `mmmmm` value in the variable `$child`.

Also, I am trying to capture all of the children spawned off of this process so I can kill each process in order of LIFO. I was going to use the above code in a while loop, but I am certainly open to suggestion.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the errors that you received.

Comment: the edit has been put in, thank you in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$reponse` does not contain a PID value.

You probably want to use `ps --no-headers`.

Comment: I mispelled response